# Intel instruction set extension and user machine (AVX, IMCI...)

Tags: c++, intel, processor, hpc, xeon-phi

If a program is compiled on a Xeon-Phi coprocessor, and contains instructions from IMCI instruction set extension, is it possible to run it on a user machine with no Xeon-Phi coprocessor ?

If it is possible, will the performance be improved on the user machine, compared to same application with no IMCI instructions compiled for instance on a i7 Core processor ?

In other words, to benefit from increased performance when using Intel instruction set extension, is it necessary that the user machine has a processor which is supporting this extension ?

Comment: Are you asking whether a CPU needs to support the instructions you send it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a program is compiled on a Xeon-Phi coprocessor, and contains instructions from IMCI instruction set extension, is it possible to run it on a user machine with no Xeon-Phi coprocessor ?

If your program use *IMCI* you need a processor (or coprocessor, this is relative) that support that instructions.
This is true for every instruction you use.

Actually I'm aware of only Intel Xeon Phi coprocessors that support *IMCI*, so the answer is **No**.

> If it is possible, will the performance be improved on the user machine, compared to same application with no IMCI instructions compiled for instance on a i7 Core processor ?
>
> In other words, to benefit from increased performance when using Intel instruction set extension, is it necessary that the user machine has a processor which is supporting this extension ?

I'm not sure what you are asking here, you can't use an instruction set extension not supported by the target processor, this is obvious as it is that you cannot speak russian with someone who can't understand russian.

If you try using unsupported instructions the processor will raise a *#UD* exception signaling a not recognized instruction, the program state could not advance as you cannot skip instructions in the program flow and the application will be forced to stop.

The *KNL* microarch of the Xeon Phi will support *AVX512* which is also supported by "mainstream" CPU.

This question may be useful: [Are there SIMD(SSE / AVX) instructions in the x86-compatible accelerators Intel Xeon Phi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670205/are-there-simdsse-avx-instructions-in-the-x86-compatible-accelerators-intel)

Also note that you should see Xeon Phi (as it is now) as a coprocessor compatible with the IA32e architecture rather than as member of IA32e family.

Comment: then, if I compile a software application on Xeon + Xeon-phi, using AVX2 and IMCI and send it to end-users, end-users cannot run it without a Xeon-Xeon-phi architecture, right ? then, is it possible to write code with a switch on the end-user supported instruction set extension, to propose optimization to those users supporting the extension ?

Comment: @octoback Yes, the switch is usually how it is done. Actually you test if an instruction set extension is available, if it is you use it, otherwise some fallback code that use standard instructions.

Comment: What is the syntax and the approach for checking the end-user architecture?

Comment: @octoback If you use the Intel Compiler you can use the [predefined macros](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/514528). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260490/how-to-check-with-intel-intrinsics-if-avx-extensions-is-supported-by-the-cpu) also.