# YASM: vmovaps instruction causing segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, memory-alignment, avx

**Problem**: `movaps` is giving me a segmentation fault.

**Context**: The x86-64 instruction `vmovaps` is designed to be used with the AVX registers on a Core i series processor (which I am running this system with). The AVX registers are twice as wide as the SSE ones (256 vs 128 bits respectively). Instruction `vmovaps` should move a vector of aligned floating-point values (32-bits) into the specified `ymm` register.

**Likely Cause:** The alignment of the source data is of particular importance, as incorrectly aligned data is a source for segmentation faults. However, even when I have aligned my data, I am encountering a segmentation fault myself.

### Example

```
    segment .data

align 16
xs:
    dd  0.0
    dd  1.1
    dd  2.2
    dd  3.3
    dd  4.4
    dd  5.5
    dd  6.6
    dd  7.7

align 16
ys:
    dd  8.8
    dd  7.7
    dd  6.6
    dd  5.5
    dd  4.4
    dd  3.3
    dd  2.2
    dd  1.1

    segment .text
    global main

main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    ; Move eight 32-bit floats from "xs" into ymm0
    vmovaps ymm0, [xs]

    ; Move eight 32-bit floats from "ys" into ymm1
    vmovaps ymm1, [ys]

    ; Add all eight to each other simulatenously, put in ymm0
    vaddps ymm0, ymm1

    xor rax, rax
    leave
    ret
```

**Compiled with**: `yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 <filename>`

**Linked with**: `gcc -o <bin-name> <filename>.o`

When I run this with GDB, it simply reports it received a segmentation fault signal on the first `vmovaps` instruction. I have checked documentation on alignment and I think it is all correct. For what its worth, I am running and executing this on a i5 8600K.

I've also looked at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148636/segmentation-fault-for-vmovaps). However I can't really apply the answer to his problem to mine (something to do with his inline assembly). If anyone could weight in on this I'd be grateful!

Comment: Well, since you are already inside your debugger, how about you look at the actual address to verify it's aligned? You do realize using `ymm0` means you must have 32 byte alignment, right? So you should change to `align 32`. The manual is quite clear: _"When the source or destination operand is a memory operand, the operand must be aligned on a 16-byte (128-bit
version), 32-byte (VEX.256 encoded version)"_

Comment: @Jester I am using a guide written by Rey Sethfarth. I took his word for it, but he mentioned 16 byte alignment was required. I see he didn't exactly specify for what ... (FWIW they are 16-byte aligned in GDB. But not 32)

Comment: @Jester That was exactly the problem. I'm sorry I didn't RTFM. I just kind of stuck to this book I'm reading and stuck to the information I got from it. If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`vmovaps` with `ymm0` operand requires 32 byte alignment. To quote [the manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movaps):

> When the source or destination operand is a memory operand, the
> operand must be aligned on a 16-byte (128-bit version), **32-byte
> (VEX.256 encoded version)** or 64-byte (EVEX.512 encoded version)
> boundary or a general-protection exception (#GP) will be generated.
> For EVEX.512 encoded versions, the operand must be aligned to the size
> of the memory operand.

(emphasis added).  Linux delivers SIGSEGV to processes that cause a #GP exception.

Thus, you should change `align 16` to `align 32` for your static array of `dd` elements

Or use [`vmovups`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movups) unaligned loads, and let the hardware handle it; same speed on data that happens to be aligned, and on most CPUs also for loads/stores that don't split across a cache-line boundary.

Related: [How to solve the 32-byte-alignment issue for AVX load/store operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612190/how-to-solve-the-32-byte-alignment-issue-for-avx-load-store-operations) for C and C++ ways of aligning things, including arrays in automatic (stack) or dynamic storage.